# Displaying Two Items in Div Center and Right Align

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting the two html tags in my div to be on the same line and align center (

) and right (). I thought setting `display: inline-block;` and `float: right` would align my span to the right side of the div, but it looks like my span is appearing outside of the div tag in the current setup. Is there something that I'm doing wrong in my current setup.

[image: screenshot]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="record-card__date">
   <p>09/01/2017</p>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up record-card__glyphicon"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .record-card__date {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #014421;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
        margin: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    }

.record-card__glyphicon {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a block level `<p>` element which will occupy 100% of the space. Then trying to force an inline element in the same line. It would be far better just to insert your icon into the paragraph at the end and accomplish the same thing by floating your icon to the right.

```
 <p>09/01/2017
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up record-card__glyphicon"></span>
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The p element is a block element, so it automatically creates a line break.  All you need to do is have both the p element and span elements be set to "inline-block".  You do not need to use "float" at all. Using float:right; takes the element out of flow, which is why it's not showing inside the div.

```
.record-card__glyphicon {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.record-card__date p {
display:inline-block;
}
```